# Unity 3D signed apps and the Facebook SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've setup the Facebook SDK in my game correctly as it works when I run it unsigned on my device but as soon as I sign the app with my key it doesn't work anymore. Does somebody have a solution for this? btw I'm using Android

Answer (score 0):

You must add your release Key Hash into your Facebook App Page Settings (and not only the "Debug Android Key Hash" given in Unity). I had the same problem after signing my app.

One way to find out the new key hash is launching the Android Monitor (sdk\tools\monitor.bat), to see the logs when you're trying to connect to faceboook from your app. The Release Key Hash should be written in the logs.